# Suspected Fragmentation in Linux Kernel Memory

Tags: linux

My system generates a "page allocation failure, order 2". Which I understand it tried to allocate 16k of contiguous memory. It then goes on a OOM killing spree.

The memory diagnostic in the kernel log looks like this:

```
Feb 26 14:53:10 [345045.509855] DMA: 2831*4kB 2136*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 28412kB
```

I'd say I had quite of lot of singleton blocks and none of any reasonable size. Hence fragmentation.

Am I correct that I am seeing fragmentation? Is there a way to find the cause or prevent it?

Ideally I would prefer my processes not die.

Additional Info. It runs for several days before OOM killing happens. This is from 'top' shortly after the system started.

top - 09:51:04 up 19:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.99, 0.37, 0.17
Tasks: 149 total,   1 running, 145 sleeping,   1 stopped,   2 zombie
Cpu(s): 47.7%us, 37.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  9.3%id,  0.0%wa,  5.3%hi,  0.6%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    254244k total,   160956k used,    93288k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    69344k cached

Isn't buddyinfo pretty much the same information as the memory diagnostic I have above? /proc/slabinfo is enourmous

Comment: Okay, so you're getting low-ish order page fragmentation. We need to know what your workload is, and a lot more memory diagnostic output to help you. We need buddy info, slab info, and way more detail on your memory capacity and what's using it.

Comment: What sort of memory diagnostics would be appropriate?

Comment: It's hard to say at this point. We need to know more about your workload. What does this machine do? What is connected to it? Also, why do you not have a swap device? A swap device is instrumental when migrating pages between nodes or consolidating pages.

Comment: It's an embedded device so swap is suppressed. Past systems have worked fine. Events occur at the rate of about 2 per second. The application processes don't appear to have a memory leak (monitoring USS and RSS). Is there a way to analyse memory allocation to try and work out what is fragmenting memory? Analyse slabinfo maybe?